# MySQL on Windows or GNU/Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows-server

I've just read this article:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/move_from_microsoft_SQL_Server.html

There it says that MySQL on Windows is a good choice. (or is what I've understood)

In the article I don't understand if he says that MySQL on Windows is better than on Linux, or just that MySQL on Windows is good enough as Linux.

Now my doubt is:
if I can choose a server dedicated to MySQL and I have to choose between Windows Server 2012 and a free GNU/Linux server distro, which one would have better performances?

May you guys help me understand this?

Comment: This may be just a layman's unsupported observations but we moved mysql from Windows to Ubuntu and the performance appears better even when the machine specifications are inferior than the Windows server.

Answer (score 2):

There are advantages of using Linux as you base for mysql, as others have already covered, *but* from a performance point of view for many applications you will not see the difference particularly.

While Linux would be my default recommendation too make sure you consider your experience (and that of the people you can immediately call upon if something goes wrong). If you are familiar with Windows but have little sysadmin experience with Linux, go with Windows. Having the knowledge to fix certain things when they go wrong may prove much more important than a performance gain while things are going right, and if got know Windows like the back of your hand you may be able to tune it to the point where it performs better than a similar Linux install that you might produce. Likewise if you have a preference for or more experience with Linux go with that for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use MySQL on Linux. There are very good reasons why Linux is a better over windows, but some of the big ones are; stability, security and total operating costs. Granted, with Linux it may be more complicated to set-up configs and daemons to ensure your server is running properly, but in the end, it is worth the setup.

You might have heard about LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL PHP/Perl/Python) for online applications. LAMP is a proven technology stack used by the most popular Web sites in the world including Facebook, Google, Twitter, YouTube, Craigslist and Zappos.

Go ahead with Linux ....

Comment: Thanks I know that GNU/Linux servers have lot of advantages, in fact I use them usually. But my question is just about the performances of MySQL on the two different platforms.

Comment: This is something like you have to benchmark yourself.. but MySQL claims there is significant gain in performance using v5.5 than v5.1 on Windows http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/5.5/mysql-55-faster-on-windows.html

Comment: You can easily imagine that perform this kind of benchmark is quite expensive, this is why I've asked here.

Comment: Yes.. I can understand but there are lot of factors involved .. Have a look at this poll which clearly states Linux is winner http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/30/what-operating-system-do-you-run-mysql-on-in-production/

Comment: I don't think a poll like that can states a winner, most of people use a Linux server just because they have it for the rest of their websites/applications or because MS is too expensive.

Comment: You can't find specific benchmaking with latest MySQL versions which is any user is interested in, rather than believing in others data or opnion .. benchmark yourself and see.